# Swift Decodable from JSON using wildcard keys

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm looking for an elegant way to decode a Swift struct from JSON.

The JSON contains an array of objects formatted like this:

```
{ 
  "id"         : "...",
  "name"       : "...",
  "component1" : "...", 
  "component2" : "...",
  "component3" : "...",
  ...
  "componentN" : "...",
  "detail1"    : "...",
  "detail2"    : "...",
  "detail3"    : "...",
  ...
  "detailN"    : "..."
}
```

Each object should be represented by a struct, which should be formatted like this:

```
struct DesiredStruct {
  var name: String?
  var components: [Component : Detail?]
}
```

For example, for the data:

```
"id"          : "0xABC"
"name"        : "Example"
"component1"  : "C1"
"component2"  : "C2"
"component3"  : null
...
"component12" : null
"detail1"     : "D1"
"detail2"     : null
...
"detail12"    : null
```

I'd like to have the following struct, which matches each numbered component and detail in a Dictionary:

```
struct DesiredStruct {
  var name = "Example"
  var components = ["C1" : "D1", "C2" : nil]
}
```

Although components can be null in the JSON data, only non-null components should be stored. However, non-null components can have null detail values.

Could you please help me to solve this? I've been looking for a way to match against keys with numeric wildcard characters in order to solve this, but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Do `detailX` and `detailY` have the same type? Is that really a number or are you looking for specific names? What is inside `componentX`? What exactly is `Component`?

Comment: Each value is either String or null. The keys are numbered. I want to store all non-null values for the `component` keys and associate them with the matching `detail` keys.

Comment: The duplicate question should help you.